# Raspberry pi Qt bluetooth module non functional ,dummy backend running

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, qt

Hello I am working on a project where i use Qt creator on ubuntu 16.04 to cross-compile on raspberry pi 3b +. for my project requirement I need to use Bluetooth with Qt environment hence QtBluetooth module, I made the module in creator following step 16 and then made raspberry pi from scratch .In between step 6 to step 8 i installed necessary libraries of bluetooth on RPi as suggested from this [link](http://www.bytran.org/qtrpicrosscompile.htm) and proceeded to complete the p[procedure still I get the same error as always qt.bluetooth: dummy back-end running, QtBluetooth module is non-functional. 
Is their some step missing or some additional process required to be done?
i am cross compiling on raspbian stretch lite os.